# MUIDataTable : onRowclick show data from json in selectable tooltip rather then as a column

Tags: reactjs, material-ui, mui-datatable

In react, I have added a MUIDataTable, I have some data in JSON which I wish to show as a tooltip on row click or hover rather than as a column.

MUI table if I don't add the hidden column name in the columns, it won't even show up in the table...

```
<MUIDataTable
            columns={columns}
            options={options}
            data={list.filter((row) => row.age > 30 && row.age < 60)}
          />
```

---

```
const columns = this.generateCols();
const options = {
  searchOpen: true,
  pagination: true,
  rowsPerPage: 160,
  rowsPerPageOptions: [160],
  selectableRowsHeader: false,
  print: false,
  filter: true,
  selectableRows: 'single',
  selectableRowsOnClick: true,
  rowHover: true,
};
```

---

```
generateCols = () => {
  return [
{
      name: "hiddenData",
      options: {
      //    customBodyRender: (value, tableMeta, updateValue) => {
      //     onRowSelectionChange: (value) => {
      //       alert(value);
      //       return (
      //               <Tooltip>
      //                 <Done color="primary" />
      //               </Tooltip>
      //             );
      //     }
      // },
        onRowSelectionChange: (value) => {
          alert(value);
          return (
                  <Tooltip>
                    <Done color="primary" />
                  </Tooltip>
          );
        }
      },
]}
```

// Have been looking in https://github.com/gregnb/mui-datatables/blob/7558e7393b6ee4b21c9481613429efcdbe7a6ddc/src/MUIDataTable.js for more understanding

Answer (score 0):

```
            customBodyRender: (value, tableMeta) => (
             
                <Tooltip 
                
                disableTouchListener
                title={tableMeta.rowData[1]}
                >
                <Button id={`${tableMeta.rowIndex}_${tableMeta.columnIndex}`} 
                    onClick={(event) => this.handleTooltipOpen(event, tableMeta, tableMeta.rowData)}>
                      {value === null ? '' : value}
                </Button>
              </Tooltip>
            )
```